# JSF 2.2 Facelet taglib not found for passthrough attribute

Tags: java, eclipse, html, taglib, jsf-2.2

I am trying to use placeholders from HTML5 but I am getting a warning when including the taglib:

```
xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
```

The warning is saying it cannot locate the tag library

```
NLS missing message: CANNOT_FIND_FACELET_TAGLIB in: 
org.eclipse.jst.jsf.core.validation.internal.facelet.messages
```

But when using the following tag anyway

```
<h:inputText class="box" pt:placeholder="Message"/>
```

This does actually render the placeholder (when not using eclipse inbuilt browser) so the tag library appears to be there.

I am wondering is there either a way to disable this warning or preferably force eclipse to find the library? Having looked about for a solution I've seen that it may be an issue with JSF Mojarra 2.2 but I can't seem to update it to the latest (2.25 I think) in eclipse.

Comment: The files are actually here: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/index.html

Comment: Im not sure what do do with that page, how do I include those schemas ?

Comment: i did not find anything except the bug reported here https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=451509

Answer (score 0):

there is one way to make the warning message disappear.
go to the "problems" tab below your workspace you should see the warning message there right-click and delete.

PS: this doesn't actually solve anything but you will get rid of that warning if its annoying you

Answer (score -1):

The error can be removed by typing `xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"` `instead of xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"`
because the links have changed and the browser is unable to reach the older link.